# Create a debian package with dependency from new repository

Tags: linux, dependencies, repository, package, debian

I need my .deb package to depend from rsync >= 3.1.0.

The problem is that it must be installed in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (precise), that provides rsync 3.0.9: if I specify the "Depends" option, the dependency won't be satisfied.

I know that, manually, I can:

1. Add a repository containing rsync 3.1.0 to `/etc/apt/sources.list` (i.e. http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main)
2. `apt-get update`
3. `apt-get install rsync`

And my rsync will get updated to 3.1.0.

So, how can I have this automatically done by my .deb package installation?

Comment: this sounds like a *very bad* idea to begin with.